# ImportError: cannot import name Serializer

Tags: python, python-2.7, xbrl

I am using python 2.7 and trying to run python-xbrl package. Following exact instructions [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-xbrl), but every time I try `import xbrl` or `from xbrl import XBRLParser, GAAP, GAAPSerializer` I get

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-ccb496289539> in <module>()
----> 1 import xbrl

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xbrl/__init__.py in <module>()
      6 version = (1, 1, 0)
      7 
----> 8 from .xbrl import XBRLParser, GAAP, GAAPSerializer, XBRLParserException

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xbrl/xbrl.py in <module>()
      3 
      4 import re
----> 5 from marshmallow import Serializer, fields
      6 import datetime
      7 import collections

ImportError: cannot import name Serializer
```

So far I have updated all the required packages (`pytest, pep8, marshmallow, beautifulsoup4, ordereddict, lxml, six`) and updated  `python-xbrl`, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a known issue, as seen [here](https://github.com/greedo/python-xbrl/issues/21).

We just have to install the latest update from github.
`sudo pip install git+https://github.com/greedo/python-xbrl.git`

Comment: thanks this helped me. what kind of things are you working on w this library?

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of the marshmallow version. Try -

```
pip uninstall marshmallow
pip install marshmallow==1.2.6
```

Comment: did that, and reinstalled `python-xbrl`, unfortunately still have the same problem.

Comment: Don't reinstall python-xbrl, I think it will upgrade the marshmallow version. Can you dod pip freeze to check the current marshmallow version?

Comment: It doesn't upgrade marshmallow version. I figured out the problem though. marshmallow package uses `serializer` not `Serializer`, so
`from marshmallow import serializer` works.

Comment: When I did the process on my computer it did upgrade the marshmallow. But as long as it now works, everything is good.

Comment: Not really. If I want to run python-xbrl package, I need to change files in that package for them to call `serializer` instead of `Serializer`, but I can't since I am not the owner of the files.

Comment: Thanks for posting this problem on python-xbrl github